# TypeError: 'ChannelParticipants' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

я ищу пользователя в чате чат на 90000 человек. После долгих раздумий код отдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: 'ChannelParticipants' object is not subscriptable
```

Код:

```
client.connect()
client.get_dialogs()
client.get_participants(-1001793665485)
entity = client.get_entity(id_users)
client.send_message(entity, 'sup')
client.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаёте в метод `Client.get_entity` всех участников, а нужно по одному:

```
for participant in client.iter_participants(-1001793665485):
    client.send_message(participant, 'sup')
    ...
```

И никаких долгий раздумий нет. Просто получение 90k человек задача не быстрая.
И вы безусловно получите спамблок после отсылки стольких сообщений без какой-либо задержки.